# Git Commit without using command line

Tags: git, command-line, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree, git-commit

I'm new in git and I'm using sourcetree on a bitbucket server. I created a repo and I can upload and commit files and folders with command line properly.

On sourcetree I can see all the branches and the uploaded files. Now I want to do all this stuff manually by drag and drop files in the specific folder, if I try to do that on sourcetree I get a message "uncommitted file".

I've already configured my mail and username by command line, maybe I have to configure other things?

So is there a way to upload file without using the command line?

Comment: Your language leads me to think that you are confused about how Git works.  You don't upload individual files, you _version_ all of them each time you make a commit.  Have you read a SourceTree tutorial?

Answer (score 0):

You have to know that GIT isn't that easy. With an commit you only save changes to your Version (branch).

I suggest you go through a tutorial (I recomment the Atlassian Tutorial https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/) and work with the bash to understand how GIT works

Comment: "Git isn't that easy" is a naive way to look at it. I think the truth is closer to "Git is much more useful than that."